# Query is not grouping

Tags: sql-server

Im filling a table and I need this table get the daily sells, but summing and counting, sells and clients by day respectively.

But is not grouping the sales by day this is the QUERY:

```
    insert into VentaDiariaTienda(
Fecha,
VentaDia,
Tda_Codigo,
NumeroClientes,
PromedioVtaCliente,
EditName,
EditDateTime)
        select 
        DATENAME(dw, T_Fecha) + ', ' + 
    cast(datepart(dd, T_Fecha) as char(2)) + ' ' + 
    datename(mm, T_Fecha) + ' ' +
    cast(datepart(yyyy,T_Fecha) as char(4)),
    sum(T_ImporteTotal/1.16),
    [FolTda_Codigo],
    count(T_Cliente),
    sum(T_ImporteTotal/1.16)/count(T_Cliente),
    'Admin',
    GETDATE()
         from #Tickets
         group by T_Fecha,[FolTda_Codigo]
```

and this is the out of this query

[image]

Thanks for your replys.

Comment: Is T_Fecha a datetime, and is it more granulate than the day?  In other words, does it go down to the hour or the minute?

Comment: Yes, it´s a datetime. But I dont want it. the source is: 2018-09-29 09:18:03.957

Comment: So, when you group by a column, it groups on all identical values. If you have values to the minute, it groups to the minute. In your case, you want to group by day, so you need to convert your grouping column to be just the date.  What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: Its Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to "round down" the `T_Fecha` values to a day, so you might try to insert the following records:

```
SELECT
  DATENAME(dw, dt) + ', ' + 
  DATENAME(dd, dt) + ' ' + 
  DATENAME(mm, dt) + ' ' + 
  DATENAME(yy, dt),
  SUM(T_ImporteTotal)/1.16,
  FolTda_Codigo,
  COUNT(T_Cliente),
  SUM(T_ImporteTotal)/1.16/COUNT(T_Cliente),
  'Admin',
  GETDATE()
FROM #Tickets
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, T_Fecha), 0))
) d (dt)
GROUP BY dt, FolTda_Codigo
```

Comment: This was the answer, but I want to know more about CROSS APPLY. Thanks!!!

Comment: CROSS APPLY works similar to an INNER JOIN with a subquery. It can SELECT records or just return VALUES (like in my answer). The main advantage over a JOIN is that it can use values from the left side for whatever purpose on the right side, not only like in a JOIN condition but also for parameters inside the subquery. In my example, the CROSS APPLY is used mainly to supply a short name (`d.dt`) for a lengthy expression that is used multiple times in the query. If you dive a little deeper into that topic, you will also find an OUTER APPLY that can be similarly compared to a LEFT OUTER JOIN. :-)

Answer (score 2):

My proposition:

1. You can use format function (since SQL Server 2012, else use Wolfgang Method)
2. Be carefull with divide by "Count" function. If you result is 0 (by example if T_Client is always null) you will have an error
3. Not necessary to use "outer apply" instruction in this case, group on by date and not by date and time

Something like this:

```
SELECT
  FORMAT(T_Fecha, 'dddd, dd MMMM yyyy', 'en-US' ), 
  SUM(T_ImporteTotal)/1.16,
  FolTda_Codigo,
  COUNT(T_Cliente),
  case when COUNT(T_Cliente)=0 then null else SUM(T_ImporteTotal)/1.16/COUNT(T_Cliente) end,
  'Admin',
  GETDATE()
FROM #Tickets
GROUP BY cast(T_Fecha as date), FolTda_Codigo
```

For SQL Server 2008, replace format by

```
DATENAME(dw, T_Fecha) + ', ' + DATENAME(dd, T_Fecha) + ' ' + 
DATENAME(mm, T_Fecha) + ' ' +  DATENAME(yy, T_Fecha),
```